# Flask server not working when there is an active socket connection using multiprocessing module

Tags: python, flask, server, multiprocessing, listener

When I am using `multiprocessing` module to establish a socket connection between a flask server and a client, the flask server fails to load the pages (routes).

Here is a minimal reproducible code:

Client.py

```py
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener

port_number = 9000

listener = Listener(('localhost', port_number), authkey=b'secret password') ------------------
conn = listener.accept() ------------------
print("connection accepted form flask server") ------------------

while True:
    msg = conn.recv()
    print(msg)
```

Server.py

```py
from multiprocessing.connection import Client
from flask import Flask

port_number = 9000

conn = Client(('localhost', port_number), authkey=b'secret password')
print("connection established with client")
conn.send("first message")

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def welcome():
    return "hello world"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In the above codes, if `client.py` is run and then `server.py` is run, then the flask app's home page does not return "hello world".

But when the 3 marked lines are commented in the `client.py` file, i.e., when the sockets are not used for connection, then the above-mentioned issue does not occur.

In the above-mentioned codes, if the socket connection from the `server.py` is made with any other files, then also the flask app does not work.

What could be the reason for this??
I am unable to find some obvious logical reason for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move `conn.send("first message")` to another thread and change port for Flask app, your code above blocks Flask server from running.

**your server:**

```py
from multiprocessing.connection import Client
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread
import time

FLASK_PORT = 9000
PR_PORT = 8000


def thread_target_func():
    """send all this actions to another thread"""
    conn = Client(('localhost', PR_PORT), authkey=b'secret password')
    print("connection established with client")
    try:
        # let's add while loop to male client to be busy with smth
        # otherwise you'll get error in client soon - EOF
        while True:
            conn.send("first message")
            time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def welcome():
    return "hello world"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # start you connection in another Thread
    th = Thread(target=thread_target_func)
    th.start()
    # run Flask app in main thread
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=FLASK_PORT)
    th.join()
```

**your client:**

```py
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener

PORT = 8000

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener = Listener(('localhost', PORT), authkey=b'secret password')
    conn = listener.accept()
    print("connection accepted form flask server")

    while True:
        msg = conn.recv()
        print(msg)
```

Comment: But the starting of flask server is displayed that means flask server is able to run anyways. And since everything is single threaded, hence i dont think there is some blocking. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Your Flask server is blocked by the connection which runs on the same port (it is not closed after `conn.send("first message")` in your server script), change port from 9000 to 8000 in both client and server scripts, but keep Flask app still run on port 9000 `app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=9000)` and it will work this way. Another option, send to client script stop message `conn.send("stop!")`, so only Flask app will stay on this port. Or use Thread like in my example, if you want to use 9000 port for both Flask app and for Connector. So you have 3 or more options to make it work.

Comment: @AbhayPatil I edited answer and gave connection and Flask app different ports, since just moving connection to another thread works not on all OS